# Object generator based on given class

Tags: wcf, service, generator

I am testing some WCF service. What I want to is to have a object generator for given classes. Then I will send the object as parameter to WCF service. It need to traverse the (nested) data member of the class and do data generate for each of them of different data types. It's great if it can be defined some rules e.g. certain data member can only have the value from a enum.

Could some one give me some direction on this?